# C++ Use offsetof without typing the type of the structure

Tags: c++, g++

Can I use offsetof to get the offset of a member within a structure without typing the actual type of the structure? (It is too long to type, it was declared with auto, etc.)

This for example works:

```
size = sizeof( some_array[0].some_member);
```

This does not:

```
offset = offsetof( some_array[0], some_member);
```

It says "some_array does not name a type". Can't use typeof( some_array) either, it says "error: expected type-specifier before typeof".
(g++ 5.4.0)

Comment: You can use `decltype`, however

Comment: Thanks! It works if it's not an array. If I use it as offsetof( decltype( some_array[0]), some_member); it says: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void*’ to type ‘main(int, char**)::SomeStruct&*’

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Or try `std::remove_reference<decltype(some_array[0])>::type`

Comment: @StoryTeller My bad, it works now with remove_reference, thank you!